# How to make a printer-friendly version of a webpage?

Tags: html, css, print

What solutions or techniques exist for offering users a printer-friendly versions of a webpage?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I do a basic css stylesheet that I setup for "print" CSS media type.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/print.css" media="print"  />
```

In this stylesheet, I'll generally do a few things:

- Hide any navigation elements that aren't relevant.
- Hide any search elements.
- Modify fonts and colors
- Modify any widths that don't mesh with a printed page.

Comment: Would be nice to see an example if at all possible.

Comment: [shameless plug] I have it implemented on http://www.isearchnotes.com/single.php?id=59 view the print preview. to See.

Comment: +1 - this is the best way of doing it... though newspapers often have separate page action where they reformat and disable pagination.  Now if only Chrome had a print preview function...

Comment: Here's a bit more detail: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/goingtoprint/

Comment: Oh yes, and this one: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/02/21/printing-the-web-solutions-and-techniques

Both good resources. The first link I posted gives a nice overview though that is probably good enough.